# How to handle onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I am blocking in onActivity result.

Activity A `startActivityForResult()`  to Activity B, Some business reason i am removing activity B and moving to till Activity F. From Activity F have to send `setResult()` to Activity A same time i have to clear stacks while moving to Activity A.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: "How to handle this scenario?" -- redesign your app to avoid what you are doing. `startActivityForResult()` is designed for *very simple scenarios*. You could combine Activity B through Activity F into a single activity. Or, you could replace `startActivityForResult()` with `startActivity()`, have F start A using `startActivity()` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` (assuming you want A to be the task root), and find some other way for A to find out the "result".

Answer (score 0):

We can use a flag from `Intent` class (didn't try myself) -`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`

Right before calling `finish()` in each of your middle actvities, you must be making a call to `startActivity(intent)`. Pass this flag to this `intent`:

```
showC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
```

In your last activity, do the regular `setResult()` ceremony. And then try to get result in your first activity as usual.

Comment: is this really  proper way to achieve this?

Comment: if two or three activities we could do but same time clear the stack as well

Comment: Technically, I don't see whats wrong in this. Try it.

Comment: i was tried this, but i cannot go with this to all other activities.

Comment: @Boopathi Since, you need to `finish()` each activity and hence can not make a chained call to `startActivityForResult()`, `onActivityResult()` and `setResult(). I don't see how it can work in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

using intent start ActivityF and pass result to ActivityA using intent.putExtra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityF.this, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("RESULT", "result to ActivityA");
startActivity(intent);
```